# Split QString with split index

Tags: qt, qstring

I need to split a qstring into two strings but knowing only the index of the splitter charachter. Here's an exaple

```
input:
PineApple
3 

Output:
Pine  // 'e'  has index 3, so it is the splitter char and it belongs to the first part
Apple
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use the [`left`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#left) and [`mid`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#mid) methods to extract the portions of the string before and after an `offset`:

```
quint32 offset = 4;
QString test("PineApple");
QString before = test.left(offset); // Pine
QString after = test.mid(offset); // Apple
```

If you're looking to end up with a `QStringList` (as you would have if you'd used `split`), you can obtain one like so:

```
QStringList list;
list << before 
     << after;
```